# Making a synchronous loop from synchronous callbacks with node.js + async module

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, async.js, node-async

The popular node.js module [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) includes functions for collections and control flow which, with versions of some which can be operate in parallel or in series.

But among them I cannot find a way to construct a loop which operates in series.

I'm trying to do the same as this pseudocode:

```
forever {
    l = getline();

    if (l === undefined) {
        break;
    } else {
        doStuff(l);
    }
}
```

- If I wanted all the calls to `getLine()` to be called in parallel I could use `async.whilst`.
- If I wanted to iterate over an array rather than make something like a `for` or `while` loop I could use `async.eachSeries`.

**What can I use to get the `series` behaviour in control flow rather than collection iteration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async.whilst` *does* execute its function serially like you need, so you can do something like this:

```
var l = getline();
async.whilst(
    function () { return l !== undefined; },
    function (callback) {
        doStuff(l);
        l = getline();
        callback(); // Check function isn't called again until callback is called
    },
    function (err) {
        // All done
    }
);
```

Comment: This leads me to ponder what advantage `async.whilst()` has over `while`; and also whether there would be any cases in which an actual asynchronous loop construct would make sense.

Comment: @hippietrail In your case where `doStuff` is synchronous, a simple `while` is a better choice.  But if `doStuff` is asynchronous, then `whilst` would make sense.

Comment: Actually my `getLine()` is asynchronous though my pseudocode was to "pseudo" to reveal that (-; So I think there is still the benefit. The other one I can think of is that the logic counting and checking whether the loop should end can become a buried detail as the meat of the function grows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute loop in series like a synchronous code, you should use async.series or async.waterfall

> series(tasks, [callback])
>
> Run an array of functions in series, each one running once the
>   previous function has completed. If any functions in the series pass
>   an error to its callback, no more functions are run and the callback
>   for the series is immediately called with the value of the error. Once
>   the tasks have completed, the results are passed to the final callback
>   as an array.
>
> waterfall(tasks, [callback])
>
> Runs an array of functions in series, each passing their results to
>   the next in the array. However, if any of the functions pass an error
>   to the callback, the next function is not executed and the main
>   callback is immediately called with the error.

Waterfall chains callbacks to pass output of one as input of next, series just executes in series.

Comment: Thanks but you might not have seen in my question how my problem doesn't involve a list of tasks and both of these functions explicitly take a list of tasks.